# SQL Server query to display all users based on case count

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, isnull

I have a "users" table as below

```
User_Id  User_Name Case_Id   Create_Date     Close_date
--------------------------------------------------------

1         abc        65473      2018-03-14   2018-03-15
2         xyz        43526      2018-03-14     NULL
3         gst        49088      2018-03-11     NULL
```

I want to display the output as below , user who has no cases open on current day (2018-03-16) should also be displayed

```
User_ID   User_Name  Case_Count

1            abc       0
2            xyz       1
3            gst       1
```

I have written below query to achieve this

```
select user_name,isnull(count(CASE_ID),'0') as case_id from users where CLOSE_DATE is NULL group by user_name
```

But I am not getting the output i want, instead i am getting this

```
User_ID   User_Name  Case_Count

2            xyz       1
3            gst       1
```

Can someone please help me with this as I am new to SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a conditional SUM of the number of cases that are still open?

In which case, you only want to include counts of cases where the `CLOSE_DATE IS NULL`, but don't want to ignore rows where the `CLOSE_DATE IS NOT NULL`, just show their total as 0:

```
   SELECT
      user_name,
      SUM(CASE WHEN CLOSE_DATE IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CASE_COUNT
    FROM users 
    GROUP BY user_name;
```

**Edit:**
You appear to have user_id in your result set, but not source query, so probably want to include that...

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  user_name,
  SUM(CASE WHEN CLOSE_DATE IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CASE_COUNT
FROM users 
GROUP BY user_id, user_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have  `where CLOSE_DATE is NULL` you won't get the first row since it has a value for close date.

Change your query to the following to make it work:

```
select user_name,count(isnull(CASE_ID),'0') as case_id from users group by user_name
```

Comment: Please remember to mark as correct if this solves your problem.

Comment: The query is not working,it is showing the total case count of the user from the beginning of time.Whereas current day,the case count of the user abc is 0

Comment: Ah sorry. I misunderstood. Well, then I just answered partially. Sorry.

Comment: SELECT
  user_id,
  user_name,
  SUM(CASE WHEN CLOSE_DATE IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CASE_COUNT
FROM users 
GROUP BY user_id, user_name;

Comment: Thanks you for replying